# Generate Apache public key from private key

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, apache2

What are the steps to generate a SSL compatible public key out of a private key generated by my server hosting service provider? 
Here are parts of the key, it's an RSA private key it seems.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAqy0rpDUVRzxHsFr4#FET5iSNVkIljgN75jQi4W7DOtAf6BWk
umcLMLIxBaQl3m7/1X93lW5EpyIa/+IqlLH0fUwMyURY6UHJ5WP/LOiV8xs2+xoJ
3LtXdMGjHEyOoSuNcJCiP4nsoYUOvxn9A37vxYnJ3Z5a9lcTQNZSorQJnxDT8cmN
y/LwcgNNVDyPwTHHxgf/V6lnuZiiaCZb5ulwSbSWaHJm7+AsXf7E2oFl3YCE7nGE
NuVM9QP0sDc44oV9qG8QZqc6wGYwSEX3YegKL0hp/2se6xwK20N/KJ5b/toWqvUt
....+G3mblRn2D==
```

I do not have too much experience with this and seems I have lost the 
logs how I generated the key pair for my last years certs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all don't ever give out your private key (or even part of the private key) like you have.  Especially since that private key is not encrypted with a password.

Since you have done that, I would generate a new private key.

Normally you would just generate a certificate request based on your current private key, that way you don't need to update your private key on the server just your new certificate using the [openssl req command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/req.html).

e.g.

> openssl req -out newrequest.csr -key private.key -new

Since you should really generate a new private key, you can do instead:

> openssl req -out newrequest.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout
>   private.key

Comment: You really think this is the original private key? :) Thanks for the tips, I already found those steps and need to test them...